# Como não perder dados do app em tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Desenvolvi um app de bloco de notas, porém, sempre que fecho o app ele apaga todas as tarefas anotadas, como faço pra isso não acontecer?

Comment: Olá, seria bom se divulgasse um pouco do seu código para ajudar melhor, você pretende salvar isso onde? Banco de dados? Ou você quer fazer de forma que seja como um bloco de notas do celular, onde o que escrevi permanece?

Answer (score -1):

Algumas formas para persistir os dados:

1) Arquivos em disco: leia sobre as funções `open()`, `write()`, `read()` e `close()`, utilizadas para criar arquivos e escrever/ler dados para disco. https://panda.ime.usp.br/pensepy/static/pensepy/10-Arquivos/files.html

2) Banco de dados: o mais simples, e que já vem pronto para uso é o `sqlite`. http://pythonclub.com.br/gerenciando-banco-dados-sqlite3-python-parte1.html